# CMake Error 'The Source Does Not Appear to contain CMakeLists.txt', problems with path/library connection

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm new to **cmake**, and I'm only using Visual studio 19 Community. I have a problem with running the program. The Program is unable to find the correct path/library. Here's the command, I ran;

```
cd path/to/examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -DLEAP_ROOT="C:\Users\User\Desktop\LeapDeveloperKit_3.2.1+45911_win\LeapSDK" ..
```

Then it returns the error:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (message):
  Run CMake in a separate build directory to avoid source code contamination.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I'm workin wth Windows10 and use prompt. How do I solve it?
Here my CmakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)

project(UltrahapticsExamples)

if (CMAKE_BINARY_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Run CMake in a separate build directory to avoid source code contamination.")
endif ()

# For FindLeap.cmake
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake" "${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}")

find_package(Ultrahaptics REQUIRED)

find_package(Leap)
if (LEAP_FOUND)
    include_directories(${LEAP_INCLUDE_DIR})
else ()
    message(WARNING "Could not find Leap SDK")
endif ()

set(ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_DIR "" CACHE PATH "Ultrahaptics CSharp libraries folder")
if (NOT ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_DIR STREQUAL "" AND EXISTS "${ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_DIR}")
    find_file(ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_RUNTIME 
        NAMES libUltrahapticsCSharp.dylib libUltrahapticsCSharp.so UltrahapticsCSharp.dll 
        PATHS "${ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_DIR}")

    find_file(ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_40 UltrahapticsCSharp.NET40.dll "${ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_DIR}")
    if (ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_RUNTIME AND ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_40)
        set(ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_FOUND TRUE)
    endif()
endif()

add_subdirectory(cpp)
if (ULTRAHAPTICS_CSHARP_FOUND)
    add_subdirectory(csharp)
endif()

message(STATUS "    ========== Examples Configuration Summary =========\n")

if (LEAP_FOUND)
    message(STATUS "    Leap:            Enabled")
else ()
    message(STATUS "    Leap:            Not Found")
endif ()

message(STATUS "")
```

Comment: Are you sure you `cd`ed into the `build` directory? The error is saying you are still in your source dir.

Comment: C:\Users\User\Desktop\Windows Win64\Examples\build

Comment: what is the output of `message(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` ?

Comment: its prepared txt.file from Ultrahaptics..   https://developer.ultrahaptics.com/knowledgebase/building-sdk-examples/

Comment: Just put these two lines: 1. `message(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})` 2. `message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})` after the `project(.....)` line. Run `cmake ..` and share the output

Comment: CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:6 (message):
  Run CMake in a separate build directory to avoid source code contamination.

Comment: In the comment above, I asked you to put those 2 lines above line 6, in the CMakeLists.txt file that is giving the error. Can you do that?

Comment: ```'
project(UltrahapticsExamples)
message(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}) 
message(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})

if (CMAKE_BINARY_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR
```
so?

Comment: yes, but on separate lines.

Comment: `message("MY BINARY DIR: " ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})`
`message("MY SOURCE DIR: " ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR})`

Comment: I done in separate..

Comment: so what does the console show you? There must be two lines showing directory paths **before** the error occurs

Comment: I am trying to debug the cmake, to fix it, i need to know what you did wrong.

Comment: ```
MY BINARY DIR: C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples
MY SOURCE DIR: C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (message):
  Run CMake in a separate build directory to avoid source code contamination.
```

Comment: Why do you write in the title the error message, which does NOT appear in your case?

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that your **build** directory is same as the directory that contains the source. You need to change this to enable *out of source* build. This will keep your compiled files separate from your source code.

```
if (CMAKE_BINARY_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Run CMake in a separate build directory to avoid source code contamination.")
endif ()
```

This line checks whether your build and source directories are same, and if they, it gives a fatal error and stops the build.

Here's how to fix it:

1. Go into the directory: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples`
2. Open cmd / ps in this directory
3. Enter: `mkdir build` // create build directory
4. Enter: `cd build`   // go into this directory

After this step the console should show that you are in directory: `C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples/build`

5. Enter: `cmake -G"Visual Studio 16 2019" -DLEAP_ROOT="C:\Users\User\Desktop\LeapDeveloperKit_3.2.1+45911_win\LeapSDK" ..`

Comment: it shows:
MY BINARY DIR: C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples
MY SOURCE DIR: C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:8 (message):
  Run CMake in a separate build directory to avoid source code contamination.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Windows Win64/Examples/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

Answer (score 1):

After the project has been configured (at least, partially) as **in-source**, it is impossible to perform **out-of-source** builds:

Even if you call `cmake` from the other directory, it will behave "as if" called from the source directory.

For make **out-of-source** build accessible again, you need to cleanup build files in the source directory, namely `CMakeCache.txt` file and `CMakeFiles` directory.